# Plumbers putty or 100% silicone?

Tags: plumbing

Which is better to use under the lip edge of a pop up drain pipe on the inside of the porcelain bowl?

Comment: Plumbers putty except when installing some polished brass. Some brass fixtures will react and discolor with plumbers putty. Refer to instruction sheet which may caution you to use silicone instead.

Answer (score 3):

You want to use plumbers putty for a drain pipe like that. If you put silicone between those two parts, especially if these are new and pristine clean, you would likely never get it back out without a huge amount of work. And in trying to remove it you would risk major damage to the porcelain sink bowl.

Comment: Totally agree with putty, you may need to pull that drain 1/ or 2times a year if you have a wife, daughters and grandchildren that have long hair putty or rubber seals will be 1000 times better than silicon sealer, just saying because I just cleaned a sink again today, I love my wife’s , girls and grand daughters long hair, but I have to clean sink and tub drains at least 2x per year, never use silicone or you may need to replace the pipes even if plastic! +

Comment: I use the putty. Not a fan of the rubber seals that come with the drain pipe.  The pipe sticks up about 1/16 " .